# Linear complementarity problem - Classification

Tags: inequalities, oc.optimization-and-control

For Linear complementarity problems (LCP) like

- $\mathbf{Mz}+\mathbf{q} \ge \mathbf{0}$
- $\mathbf{z} \ge \mathbf{0}$
- $\mathbf{z}^{\mathrm{T}}(\mathbf{Mz}+\mathbf{q}) = 0$

there exists a vast amount of material and algorithms. But what about this kind of problem:

- $\mathbf{Mz}+\mathbf{q} \ge \mathbf{0}$
- $\mathbf{Az} +\mathbf{b}\ge \mathbf{0}$
- $(\mathbf{Az} +\mathbf{b})^{\mathrm{T}}(\mathbf{Mz}+\mathbf{q}) = 0$

Is it also called LCP? Can it be transformed into the form above?

The real question is, how to solve it without the need to invert on of the matrices explicitly.

Comment: Don't post to two different places simultaneously: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26541. Voting to close here.

Comment: why not? why does the appearance of a question in one forum prohibit its appearance in another forum?

Comment: @Johannes: See http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/943/. Basically, it's simply impolite to simultaneously post a question to different forums, especially if you don't give any indication that you have done so.